# Per or by default?

Tags: prepositions

In the sentence below, is it better to use *per* or *by*?

When you create a new software component, the database is used *per*/*by* default.

I've taken a look at the "By" vs "Per" question suggested below. This is close but not exactly what I was looking for. In software engineering, we tend to "enable software components per or by default". The example you state has a different context, if I understand correctly.

Comment: I've taken a look at "By" vs "Per". This is close but not exactly what I was looking for. In software engineering, we tend to "enable software components per or by default". The example you state has a different context, if I understand correctly.

Comment: Definitely use "by default".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I understand the context, but I don't think per is appropriate here, unless by default you are referring to an array or a structure with multiple items holding the default values. It may be acceptable if that is the case, but you can avoid confusion by being more explicit about the nature of the values involved.